# What does I.p. mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

The following is from a [reader's response](http://www.amazon.com/review/R3O0IO3IXM9BZK/ref=cm_cr_pr_cmt?ie=UTF8&ASIN=057109659X&linkCode=&nodeID=&tag=#wasThisHelpful) to a book review. What does `I.p.` mean?

> The reviewer is pretty much right on target and helpful in his review;
>       he nicely qualifies the benefits of the large book. I.p., his observation
>       of knots repetition is correct--he is not citing "variations".

I find no listing in [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90670?redirectedFrom=I.P.#eid1072734).

Comment: [This site](http://www.acronymfinder.com/IP.html) lists "In particular" as a possibility, that seems to fit as @Harshit suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means 'in particular'. That is a just a guess.